# Django: Incorrect dropdown valuefrom form is returned in Get request

Tags: django, http-post, django-queryset, dropdown, html-select

I am looking to perform an inventory query based on the result of a Select/drop down - I have setup the parameter obtained from a html dropdown to pass via URL that is needed to filter a queryset on another page but it is not working - I keep getingt 'No Reverse Match' error.
The dropdown value is part of a set of dependent drop down values on the homepage; 'Make' and 'Model' of cars.
I want to use the value of 'Model' to open up the available inventory on another webpage 'search_results'.
I am basically posting the value of the dropdown 'modelddl' from the 'index' page and looking to get the value on the 'search_results' page. This should then allow the query set to be filtered so that a table can be filled out. No matter what I do I do not seem to be picking up the 'Model' value in the dropdown so the table is rendering without any values.
****** Update****** Have the URls working in terms of passing a value, it is passing the value from the makeddl dropdown not the modelddl dropdown, despite specifying the dropdown name to use in the form action on the Index template.

*URL output;* http://localhost:56543/search_results/makeselection=BMW&modelselection=BMW

Despite having a value of '116d' on the 'modelselection' dropdown, the value BMW is passed which is the value of the 'makeselection' dropdown.

Updated code in comments.
Changes made are in the comments below.

Any help is much appreciated!

**Key Models**

```
 class MotorMakes(models.Model):
    MotorMakeName = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, default=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.MotorMakeName or ''
    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.MotorMakeName) or ''

class MotorModelsV2(models.Model):
    MotorMakeName =  models.CharField(max_length=50, default=False,)
    MotorModelName = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=False,)
    Mkid = models.ForeignKey(MotorMakes,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=False)
    Mlid = models.IntegerField(default=False, unique=True)
    MotorImage = models.ImageField(upload_to='Car_Pics', default=False,blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.MotorModelName or ''

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.MotorModelName) or ''

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('MotorMakeName',)

class GarageInventory(models.Model):
    MotorDetailRef = models.ForeignKey(MotorDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    GarageID = models.CharField(max_length=5, default='',)
    ListMake= models.CharField(max_length=50, default='',)
    ListSeries = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='', null=True)
    ListModel= models.CharField(max_length=50,default='')
    #ListSeries = models.ForeignKey(CarSeries, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    #ListModel= models.ForeignKey(CarModel, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', null=True)
    BodyType = models.CharField(max_length=25, default='', null=True)
    GaragePrice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default='0')
    FuelType = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='')
    Colour = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='')
    DoorType = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='', null=True)
    CarEngine = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='', null=True)
    Year = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='', null=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)

    
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s' % (self.GarageID, self.ListModel, self.ListMake, self.Title) or ''
        #return self.Model and self.Title or ''

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.Title) or ''

    class Meta:
        ordering = ( 'ListMake','ListModel','Title')
```

**Views.py**

```
def home(request): #this is the index file
    """Renders the home page."""
    displayCounty=County.objects.all()
    displayMake=MotorMakes.objects.all()
    displayModel=MotorModelsV2.objects.all()
    displayDetail=MotorDetail.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html',{'County':displayCounty, 'MotorMakesView':displayMake, 'MotorModelsView':displayModel, 'MotorDetailView':displayDetail})

 
   
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'app/index.html',
        {
            'title':'Home Page',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        }

    )

 class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = GarageInventory.objects.all()
    template_name = 'search_results.html'

    def SearchInventory(request, inputvalue=None):
        if request.method=='GET':
            inputvalue=request.GET.get('modelselection',False)
            displayInventory = GarageInventory.objects.all().filter(ListModel=inputvalue)
        else:
            displayInventory = GarageInventory.objects.all()

        return render(request, 'search_results', {'GarageInventoryView':displayInventory,})
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" integrity="sha512-nMNlpuaDPrqlEls3IX/Q56H36qvBASwb3ipuo3MxeWbsQB1881ox0cRv7UPTgBlriqoynt35KjEwgGUeUXIPnw==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                    var $makevar = $("#makeddl");
                        $modelvar = $("#modelddl");
                        $options = $modelvar.find('option');
                        $makevar.on('change',function()
                        {
                        $modelvar.html($options.filter('[value="' + this.value + '"]'));
                        }).trigger('change');
            });
        </script>
</head>


<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron" style="background-image: url(https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/59/17/83/240_F_259178343_D9wu1JKg49PF0nywVuY7K27I0bMgt7hx.jpg); background-size: 100% 110%;">
       
        <h3 style ="color:midnightblue; text-align:left; font-family:verdana">
            Take the hassle ... 
            <br>
                out of the haggle ...
            </br>
        </h3>

        <p color:white;"></p>
    </div>
</div>




<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Browse the Showroom</h2>
            <p>Choose a make, model and a county to get started</p>
            {#<! -- Drop Downs  -->#}
            <form  action = "{% url 'search_results' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %} 
                <label for="makeddl">Choose Make</label>
                    {<select id="makeddl">
                        <option  disabled selected="true">Choose Make</option>
                        {% for makes in MotorMakesView %}
                        <option value ="{{ makes.MotorMakeName}}"> {{ makes.MotorMakeName }} </option>      
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                <br><br>
                
                <label for="modelddl">Choose Model</label>
                    <select id="modelddl"> 
                        <option disabled selected ="True">Model</option>
                        {% for mods in MotorModelsView %}
                        <option value="{{ mods.MotorMakeName}}"> {{ mods.MotorModelName}} </option> 
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>}
                <br><br>
               
                <label for="countyddl">Choose County</label>
                    <select type>
                        <option>County</option>
                        {% for result in County %}
                        <option>{{result.CountyName}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                <br><br>
         
            {#<! -- Submit Button -->#} 
            
                <input type="submit" value="Get Offers" placeholder="Search...">
                
                    
                <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="/search_results">Get Offers &raquo;</a></p>
            </form>

    </div>
   
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Estimate Trade-in Value</h2>
        <p>Estimate the trade in value fo your car before speaking with the dealer.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="https://www.myvehicle.ie/faq/can-you-tell-me-what-the-true-value-of-the-car-is/">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Arrange a Loan</h2>
        <p>Apply for a loan with our partner ....</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="https://carloans4u.ie/?gclid=CjwKCAjw57b3BRBlEiwA1ImytlZI9xjld1wY7n1ln6gERfjTCtwyXoBzj_6p-41pq7UxgDkY16ChVRoC2TUQAvD_BwE">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
 
{% endblock %}
```

**search_results.html**

```
**<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
{% block content %}
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" integrity="sha512-nMNlpuaDPrqlEls3IX/Q56H36qvBASwb3ipuo3MxeWbsQB1881ox0cRv7UPTgBlriqoynt35KjEwgGUeUXIPnw==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <title>Search Results</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><Strong>Here are your deals;</Strong></h1>
    <p>
    </p>
            <table class= "table table-striped">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Garage ID</th>
                        <th scope="col">Model</th>
                        <th scope="col">Make</th>
                        <th scope="col">Title</th>
                        <th scope="col">Year</th>
                        <th scope="col">Body</th>
                        <th scope="col">Offer Price</th>
                        <th scope="col">RRP</th>
                        
                    </tr>
                </thead> 
                    {% for inv in  GarageInventoryView %}
                <tbody class = "table table-hover">
                     <tr>   
                        <td>{{inv.GarageID}}</td>
                        <td>{{inv.ListModel}}</td>
                        <td>{{inv.ListMake}}</td>
                        <td>{{inv.Title}}</td>
                        <td>{{inv.Year}}</td>
                        <td>{{inv.BodyType}}</td>
                        <td>{{inv.GaragePrice}}</td>
                        
                        {% for mods in MotorDetailsView %}
                            <td>{{ mods.id}}> {{ mods.RRP}}</td>
                        {% endfor %}
                     </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>    
            </table>
               
       
</body>
</html>
{% endblock %}**
```

**URLs.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
 url(r'^search_results/(?P<inputvalue>\D+)/$', views.SearchResultsView, name ='search_results'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Index.html - the form method is 'post' change it to 'get'

Comment: Thanks @Neeraj, no change in the error though - _italic_ 1 pattern(s) tried: ['search_results/(?P<inputvalue>\\D+)/$'] - could it be the URL or the view?

Comment: it should be in view, not is url , make url very simple like url('searchcar', views.SearchResultsView, name ='search_results'),

Comment: I was playing around with a more simplistic URL before as well so I've added that back in, now there is a new error; '__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given'

Comment: DjangoProtoV2\DjangoProtoV2\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\35386\source\repos\DjangoProtoV2\DjangoProtoV2\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\35386\source\repos\DjangoProtoV2\DjangoProtoV2\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Comment: in urls.py change views.SearchResultsView to views.SearchResultsView.as_view()

Comment: I've made that change which created a new error ; 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_default_manager' ;;;;; I've tried to create a specifc manager in models to replace the default objects all i.e. Inventory = models.Manager()  ;;;;; however this change has not had any impact.

Comment: Also via testing it doesn't look like the value of the dropdown is being picked up since the last changes, so potentially an item to fix there

Comment: the errors you are getting are very basic in nature , please refer to Django documentation

Comment: Resolved issues about passing data to the URL - now the incorrect dropdown is being passed, despite soecifying the name of the dropdown in the Get action of the form to select make and moel. Make value is being passed despite specifying Model value.

Comment: View

def SearchInventory(request):

    inputvalue = request.GET['modelselection']
    print(inputvalue)
    displayInventory = GarageInventory.objects.all().filter(ListModel=inputvalue)

    return render(request, 'search_results.html', {'GarageInventoryView':displayInventory})


URL
url(r'^search_results/$', views.SearchInventory, name ='search_results'),

Comment: Index
 <form  action = "{% url 'search_results'%}" method="get"> 
                <label for="makeddl">Choose Make</label>
                    {<select id="makeddl">
                        <option  disabled selected="true">Choose Make</option>
                        {% for makes in MotorMakesView %}
               <option value ="{{ makes.MotorMakeName}}"> {{ makes.MotorMakeName }} </option>  
                  {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                <br><br>

Comment: index contd ;;;;
                <label for="modelddl">Choose Model</label>
                    <select id="modelddl" name="modelselection"> 
                        <option disabled selected ="True">Model</option>
                        {% for mods in MotorModelsView %}
                        <option value="{{ mods.MotorMakeName}}"> {{ mods.MotorModelName}} </option> 
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>}
                <br><br>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Search" >
            </form>